# Are the static fields called/loaded every time they are used?

Tags: java, static

I have a class that contains static fields like large lists that stores keywords. Then I have static methods that work on those static fields. I was wondering if the static fields get emptied and loaded every time I call the static methods.

Comment: No they aren't. They are loaded only once when the class is loaded.

Comment: @RohitJain So if I use the class only once, it will still be loaded right?

Comment: Of course, when you use a class, it is loaded.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "emptied and loaded"?

Comment: One way to test this would be to create a class that prints "Hello, world!" in its constructor. Then create a static field as `static HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();`, and use that field in whatever use cases you're interested in. You'll see that it'll only print "Hello, world!" once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats right the static fields are loaded when the class get loaded i.e when the program starts and it remains until the program is terminated and all the objects that are created share the same value that is present in static variables

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if the static fields get emptied and loaded every time I call the static methods.

no unless you do it, static fields are initialized when class gets loaded by classloader

Comment: I only use this class for the static methods, so I wonder if the class then will still be loaded

Comment: Where should the VM take the information from what to actually execute if the class has not been loaded yet? So, the VM has to load the class although everything is defined as static

Comment: yes class will still be loaded when it is first required by jvm on runtime

Answer (score 0):

In other words static fields are always there. When the classloader loads the class then every static field has its place in the heap memory.